# Merging two json file and using it in autocoplete plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to merge two JSON file and using it in autocompleteplugin.

But I do get an error `TypeError: $(...).easyAutocomplete is not a function` even I have added js library for both auto complete and jquery.

My code look like this:

```
<script src="jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<link href="easy-autocomplete.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="jquery.easy-autocomplete.min.js"></script>



<script>
    $.getJSON("file1.json", function (data1) {
        $.getJSON("file2.json", function (data2) {
            var final = $.extend({}, data1, data2);
            var options = {
                data: final,
                getValue: "name",
                list: {
                    match: {
                        enabled: true
                    }
                },
                theme: "square"        
                };
            $("#KUNDE").easyAutocomplete(options); $('div.easy-autocomplete').removeAttr('style');
       });
     });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a working example based on your code.

Please check you have the correct paths when you include the script files. And also check if jQuery is included.

Hope will help you:

```js
$.getJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/42jd0", function (data1) {
  $.getJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/5bjqc", function (data2) {
    var final = [];
    final.push(data1.employees1);
    final.push(data2.employees2);
    var new_final = final[0].concat(final[1]);
    var options = {
      data: new_final,
      getValue: "firstName",
      list: {
        match: {
          enabled: true
        }
      },
      theme: "square"        
    };
    $("#KUNDE").easyAutocomplete(options); $('div.easy-autocomplete').removeAttr('style');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/easy-autocomplete/1.3.5/easy-autocomplete.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/easy-autocomplete/1.3.5/jquery.easy-autocomplete.min.js"></script>

<div class='easy-autocomplete'>
  <input id="KUNDE"/>
</div>
```

You can run the code here by hitting the `Run code snippet` button or you can also check the jsfiddle I've made [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wxh7qdo5/).

Comment: This has worked for me with small changes. Instead     final.push(data1.employees1); final.push(data2.employees2);

Comment: final.push(data1);
    final.push(data2);